# How to store and retrive emojis in the Firebase using Swift 2.0+

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ios9

Hi anyone can please help me how to store Emojis in Firebase? I am trying like below but the app is crashing while i run.

```
let emoji = emoji.unicodeScalars
USER_REF.childByAppendingPath(friendUID as String).childByAppendingPath("messages").setValue(emoji, forKey: "emoji")
```

My intention here was converting an emoji into unicode, and saving in to the firebase database.

Comment: Hi my intention was converting emoji into unicode, so that i can save it in the firebase database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emoticons are unicode characters and can be stored by their actual value. So for example a smile face is 1F642.

There's a wiki on that topic it has a chart and cross reference on it; search for Emoticons (Unicode_block)

To save to Firebase

```
let smiley = "\U0001F642"
smileyRef.setValue: smiley
```

To read from Firebase:

Read the value from Firebase and stuff it into a string that will allow it to be a unicode char. Then to present the string UI, assign that string to a text field that supports unicode; NSTextField in this case.

```
self.myTextField.stringValue = smiley;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.